# Copy cells to second sheet based on cell value using a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We use google sheets for our invoice system.  Once we pull the order, we fill in the invoice and anything that we do not have we backorder.  We type BO in column I.  In excel, we used a button that we could click to copy those cells to our 2nd sheet.  We need cells A & B to copy to sheet 2 (which is an exact copy of sheet 1) if column I says BO.  Here's what I have so far.  This almost works... It deletes everything above the rows with data though and copies the data even if column I doesn't have BO.

I need it to just copy Column A & B if column I says BO to sheet 2 (which is a duplicated of sheet 1) I'm sure there's a simple way, but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
function Backorder() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Carolina Fireworks Order Form");
  var columnToSearch = 9; // I column 

  Logger.log(sheet.getLastRow());
  var range =sheet.getRange(1,columnToSearch,sheet.getLastRow(),columnToSearch);
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Back Order");
  var values = range.getValues();

  //Destination  
  var numberOfColumns = 12;
  var numberOfRows = 223 ;
  var startColumn = 1;
  var startRow = 12;
                         // equivalent to destination.getRange('A1:L223');     
  var destinationRange= destination.getRange(startRow, startColumn,numberOfRows,numberOfColumns); 
  var count = '0';
  for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
    Logger.log("i is now: " +i);
    Logger.log("Current row value: " +values[i][0]) 
    if(values[i][0] == 'BO'){
      Logger.log("*** Value found in column: " +values[i][0] +"**** \n Count: " +i);
      count++;
      var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(i, 1,numberOfRows,numberOfColumns);
      rangeToCopy.copyTo(destinationRange);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

***Updated* **

The updated script below will loop through the `sourceSheet` on every row and it specifically checks if every row on column I says "BO".

If there's a match on that specific row of column I, the row # from the loop will be added to `rangeToCopy` variable (e.g. range "A(row #):B(row #)" in [A1 notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation)). Then, the `rangeToCopy` will be copied to the `destination` in the same exact range of `rangeToCopy`, given that the `destination` is the same exact copy of `sourceSheet`.

```
function backOrder(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Carolina Fireworks Order Form");
  var destination = sheet.getSheetByName("Back Order");
  var lastRow = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getLastRow();
  //LOOP THROUGH SOURCE SHEET
  for(var row=1; row<=lastRow; row++){
    //CHECK FOR "BO" ON EVERY ROWS OF COL I ON SOURCESHEET
    if(sourceSheet.getRange(row,9).getValue() == "BO"){
      Logger.log("CELL I"+row+" has \"BO\""+"\n=================\n"+"RANGE TO COPY:\n"+ "\"A"+row+":B"+row+"\"");
      var rangeToCopy = "A"+row+":B"+row;
      sourceSheet.getRange(rangeToCopy).copyTo(destination.getRange(rangeToCopy));
      sourceSheet.getRange(row,9).setValue("- BO").setHorizontalAlignment("right");
    }
  }
}
```

**RESULT**

Sample filled out *Carolina Fireworks Order Form* sheet:

[image]

The *Back Order* sheet after running the script:

[image]

Execution logs result for review:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing the sample sheets. Upon checking, it is quite unclear on how to copy Column A & B (QTY & UNIT) on the  "Back Order" sheet because it is a duplicate of "Carolina Fireworks Order Form" with same exact data.  Can you share a step-by step example on how you would copy (QTY & UNIT) from sheet 1  to sheet 2 with your sheet design? Is the main goal to only show Column A & B on sheet 2 (QTY & UNIT) and the rest of the columns are removed?

Comment: Is this sample result https://imgur.com/a/oKSSeTN the one you want to see on your "Back Order" sheet?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion!  Here is a sample that I filled out.  Order Form:  https://imgur.com/gq4vJ8Q, & Back Order: https://imgur.com/isc8Hyn.  I don't want any cells removed from sheet 2. I hide the rows that don't have any numbers in column a with a filter to print for better viewing see here: https://imgur.com/CvkwrJi. I just need the information from A&B to be moved over to the exact row on sheet 2 if column I says BO. We use sheet 2 to keep track of backorders. Often times, when we call a customer to tell them their backorder items are in then they add to that list before we deliver.

Comment: Thanks for sharing an example. I have updated my script on the posted answer, where A&B range is copied over to the exact row on sheet 2 if column I has "BO"